# Infinite sum of positive integers and why an integral test doesn't disprove it

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recreational-mathematics

### Problem

I first came across this statement
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -\frac{1}{12}$ a couple of years ago.

Why does an integral test for convergance not disprove this.
That is, with an integral of 
$$\int_0^\infty x dx$$

I see the integral test requires a monotonically decreasing function and this will be why you can't use it for the infinte sum of positive integers.
I fail to understand why this function requires a decreasing function. Perhaps this is beyond the scope of what I'm trying to understand.

### Context

I saw a video challenging the viewer to solve the [Balancing bricks problem](https://youtu.be/rXvaCy8PMdE) and I proceeded to solve it to the point of the Sum of the harmonic series which I looked up information.

I saw the integral test as a way to show this series also had an infinite sum as demonstrated in the [Harmonic Series Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Integral_Test). This immediately reminded me about that ol' friend $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n = -\frac{1}{12}$  and I was lead to wonder why that integral test couldn't be applied. Cue much internet searching and now this question.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$ does diverge. The equation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n=-\frac1{12}$ is _false_. (There is a connection between the left and right sides of that equation, but it's not of equality.)

Comment: The series is divergent by the usual definition of limit. Assigning the value $-1/12$ to its sum involves a different definition of the sum of an infinite series, called zeta function regularization. You can see wikipedia for details.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Proof.

The integral test can't be applied for the reason you said it can't: $f(x) = x$ doesn't satisfy the hypotheses of the integral test.  It sounds like the question you really want to ask (and did ask elsewhere in the post) is why the integral test requires $f(x)$ be monotonically decreasing (MD).  See the link I provided for the proof of the integral test.  The proof requires $f$ be MD.  So without $f$ being MD, the proof fails, and there's no integral test.

Answer (score 1):

Let me take an easier example.

By definition of a series, with $A_N= \sum_{n=0}^N 2^n = 2^{N+1}-1$ : $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n =  \lim_{N \to \infty} A_N = \lim_{N \to \infty}2^{N+1}-1 = +\infty$$

Now you can [regularize this divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Analytic_continuation_of_power_series) : $$\text{only for } |z| < 1, \qquad \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}, \qquad   \overset{\color{red}{(\mathcal{P})}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty} 2^n =\left.\frac{1}{1-z}\right|_{z = 2} = -1$$
where $\displaystyle\overset{\color{red}{(\mathcal{P})}}{\sum} $ means we are using the power series regularization, completely changing the meaning of the symbol $\sum$

---

Here what we are talking about is $$\overset{\color{red}{(\mathcal{Z})}}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty} n =\frac{-1}{12}$$ where $\displaystyle \overset{\color{red}{(\mathcal{Z})}}{\sum}$ is the [zeta regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Zeta_function_regularization).